# How do I center v-menu on the selected item? (Vuetify, Vue2)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-composition-api

I have a long list of selectable items using v-menu. I want to center the list on the selected item using v-list-item-group. However when using the the prop "auto" on v-menu adjusting the positioning of the menu through e.g. nudge-right seems to be broken. I want to position the menu under a text-field, but the auto prop moves it on top of the text field.

Is there another way to center a list on the selected item without the auto prop, so that I keep the wanted positioning?
Or
How can I fix the positioning of the menu while using the auto prop?

I tried setting the position through top, left etc. but since the position is absolute and the menu is attached to the document (for technical reasons we can't use the attach prop) the position would have to be calculated for each list (we have multiple lists like this on the same page) and I can't seem to access vuetify's precalculated positions and add some more pixels to them.
I also tried to use nudge-right and nudge-bottom. nudge-right doesn't do anything and nudge-bottom is inaccurate, it only works correct for 1 out of 4 items for some reason.
I feel like I'm missing something, because this is something so basic, that vuetify shouldn't make this so hard, so please enlighten me. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired behavior by manually calculating the position of the `v-menu` based on the position of the triggering element (like your `v-text-field`). This involves using JavaScript to determine the position of the text field and dynamically setting the `nudge-top` and `nudge-left` properties of `v-menu`. Here's a simplified example to illustrate this approach:

#### HTML Template:

```html
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-text-field
      ref="textField"
      label="Click me"
      @click="openMenu"
    ></v-text-field>

    <v-menu
      v-model="menu"
      :close-on-content-click="false"
      :nudge-top="nudgeTop"
      :nudge-left="nudgeLeft"
      offset-y
    >
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(item, index) in items"
          :key="index"
          @click="selectItem(item)"
        >
          <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-menu>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

#### Vue Component Script:

```js
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    menu: false,
    items: [{ title: 'Item 1' }, { title: 'Item 2' }, ...],
    nudgeTop: 0,
    nudgeLeft: 0
  }),

  methods: {
    openMenu() {
      this.menu = true;
      this.calculateMenuPosition();
    },

    calculateMenuPosition() {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        const textFieldRect = this.$refs.textField.$el.getBoundingClientRect();
        this.nudgeTop = textFieldRect.height + 10; // Adjust 10 for additional spacing
        this.nudgeLeft = textFieldRect.left;
      });
    },

    selectItem(item) {
      // Handle item selection
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

#### Explanation:

- **Text Field Reference**: The `v-text-field` has a `ref` attribute, which allows you to reference this element in your Vue component.
- **Menu Opening**: Clicking the text field triggers the `openMenu` method. This method opens the `v-menu` by setting `menu` to `true`.
- **Position Calculation**: The `calculateMenuPosition` method calculates the position of the text field and adjusts the `nudgeTop` and `nudgeLeft` data properties accordingly. `this.$nextTick` ensures the DOM is updated before getting the element's position.
- **Dynamic Menu Positioning**: The `nudge-top` and `nudge-left` props on `v-menu` are dynamically bound to the calculated position, ensuring the menu aligns under the text field.

Comment: Does this work while using the auto-prop? Because I have the problem that when using the auto prop menu to center the list on the selected item, that nudge-left/nudge-right doesn't seem to apply

Comment: I think you can use one or the other, as they are mutually exclusive I believe.